# getClass() in a static function [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to run this code in a static function?

```
Parent parent = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
```

When I declare the function which contains above line of code as static I get an error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Which I understand what does it mean. But I wonder what could I do to maintain functionality of my method and on the other hand make it static.

Comment: You cann acces the class object in a static way via the class label, for example `Parent.class`. However, you need to know the class at compile-time.

Comment: But what if I don't know the class at compile-time?

Comment: I guess you will have to work-around.

Comment: How can you not know the class at compile time when you're in a static method?  It's the class you're writing the method in.

Comment: Thanks Louis Wasserman - you made it clear for me now.